# Python "Option" to determine IF ELSE decision is not working

Tags: python, position

I'm trying to write a program for a moving position. Below here is my code.

```
def robot():
    i = input("Please enter the direction: ")
    j = input("Please enter the steps: ")
    k = int(j) #convert steps input into integer
    x = 0 #x-axis position 
    y = 0 #y-axis position
    xpos = ""
    ypos = ""

    option = 1

    if (option == 1):
        if (i == "UP"):
            y += k
            if (y > 0): 
                steps = str(y)
                print ("I am now " + steps + " steps above")
            elif (y < 0):
                steps = str(y)
                print ("I am now " + steps + " steps below")
            option = input("1 to continue moving, 0 to terminate: ")
        elif (i == "DOWN"):
            y -= k
            if (y < 0):
                steps = str(y)
                print ("I am now " + steps + " steps below")
            elif (y > 0):
                steps = str(y)
                print ("I am now " + steps + " steps above")
            option = input("1 to continue moving, 0 to terminate: ")
        elif (i == "LEFT"):
            x -= k
            if (x < 0):
                steps = str(x)
                print ("I am now " + steps + " steps behind")
            elif (x > 0):
                steps = str(x)
                print ("I am now " + steps + " steps infront")
            option = input("1 to continue moving, 0 to terminate: ")
        elif (i == "RIGHT"):
            x += k
            if (x < 0):
                steps = str(x)
                print ("I am now " + steps + " steps behind")
            elif (x > 0):
                steps = str(x)
                print ("I am now " + steps + " steps infront")
            option = input("1 to continue moving, 0 to terminate: ")
    elif (option == 0):
        xpos = str(x)
        ypos = str(y)
        print ("I am now at " + xpos + " on x-axis and " + ypos + " on y-axis")    

robot()
```

So the output is like this, it goes from asking for the direction, and then the steps. After that, it prints out how many steps in which direction AND THEN prompts user to either continue or stop.

So as you can see in the code, I added

```
option = input("1 to continue moving, 0 to terminate: ")
```

but if I enter 1 for the option, it doesn't bring me back into the loop. Can I know where or what I did wrong? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You need to use `while` loop to keep it running

Comment: I have tried changing the most outer IF into a while, but it still gets me out of the loop after prompting the user NO MATTER I put in 1 or 0.

Comment: Wrap the outer most IF in WHILE loop. Check the answer of @Steve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are **missing loop**, moreover you are not checking **condition** properly for **termination/continue**. I rewritten the code

```
i = input("Please enter the direction: ")
j = input("Please enter the steps: ")
k = int(j) #convert steps input into integer
x = 0 #x-axis position 
y = 0 #y-axis position
xpos = ""
ypos = ""

option = 1

if (option == 1):
    if (i == "UP"):
        y += k
        if (y > 0): 
            steps = str(y)
            print ("I am now " + steps + " steps above")
        elif (y < 0):
            steps = str(y)
            print ("I am now " + steps + " steps below")
        option = input("1 to continue moving, 0 to terminate: ")
        if(option=="1"):
           return 1
        else:
           return 0
    elif (i == "DOWN"):
        y -= k
        if (y < 0):
            steps = str(y)
            print ("I am now " + steps + " steps below")
        elif (y > 0):
            steps = str(y)
            print ("I am now " + steps + " steps above")
        option = input("1 to continue moving, 0 to terminate: ")
        if(option=="1"):
           return 1
        else:
           return 0
    elif (i == "LEFT"):
        x -= k
        if (x < 0):
            steps = str(x)
            print ("I am now " + steps + " steps behind")
        elif (x > 0):
            steps = str(x)
            print ("I am now " + steps + " steps infront")
        option = input("1 to continue moving, 0 to terminate: ")
        if(option=="1"):
           return 1
        else:
           return 0
    elif (i == "RIGHT"):
        x += k
        if (x < 0):
            steps = str(x)
            print ("I am now " + steps + " steps behind")
        elif (x > 0):
            steps = str(x)
            print ("I am now " + steps + " steps infront")
        option = input("1 to continue moving, 0 to terminate: ")
        if(option=="1"):
           return 1
        else:
           return 0

flag=1
while flag:
   flag=robot()
```

output:

```
 >>> 
 Please enter the direction: UP
 Please enter the steps: 1
 I am now 1 steps above
 1 to continue moving, 0 to terminate: 1
 Please enter the direction: DOWN
 Please enter the steps: 3
 I am now -3 steps below
 1 to continue moving, 0 to terminate: 0
 >>>
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not have a loop. Instead of if you should use while

Answer (score 0):

Your major problem is that you **don't** actually have a **loop** - this is shown by the lack of any of the keywords `while`, `for`, `until` - by the way the structure is ***horrible***.

Change robot to `return option` at the end and call it as:

```
flag = 1
while flag:
   flag = robot()
```